# ManyToMany Relation with Play Framework 1.2.5 JPA

Tags: jpa, orm, playframework, many-to-many, playframework-1.x

I have 2 Models `Article.java` and `Tags.java`. An `Article` can have many `Tags`, and a `Tags` can be belonged to many `Article`. I am really in trouble to make this relation using JPA and Play Framework 1.2.5. Below are my codes (without setter-getter), and actually it works even throwing exception but I can not get the `Tags` (`getTagname()`) of an `Article`

```
Article article = Article.findById((long)id);
List<Tags> tags = article.getTags();

for (Tags tags2 : tags) {
    System.out.println(tags2.getTagname());
}
```

Here is my models, **Article.java**

```
@Entity
public class Article extends Model{

    @Required
    public String title;

    @Required
    public String link;

    @Required
    @Lob
    public String description;

    public Date date;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<Tags>();
}
```

**Tags.java**

```
@Entity
public class Tags extends Model {

    @Required
    public String tagname;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags") 
    public List<Article> tagsInArticle = new ArrayList<Article>(); 
}
```

Comment: What does "I can't get the tags" mean? What happens? Any exception? If so, what's the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing something like your code provided above (and use Play 1.2.5), and it seems there is are problems found with the code you provided. The following are my step:

First, I create 2 **models** `Article.java`

```
package models;

import play.data.validation.Required;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article extends Model {
    @Required
    public String title;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
}
```

and `Tag.java`

```
package models;

import play.data.validation.Required;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag extends Model {
    @Required
    @Column(name = "tag_name")
    public String tagName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    public List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<Article>();
}
```

Then, on the database, I manually added several record for testing purpose:

> **article** (id;title) > 1;"java example" and 6;"article1"
>
> **tag** (id;tag_name) > 4;"java" and 5;"playframework"
>
> **article_tag** (articles_id;tags_id) > 6;4 and 6;5 and 1;4

So then, I testing it with the **controller** action :

```
public static void test() {
    Article article = Article.findById(6L); // find "article1"
    Tag tag_java = Tag.findById(4L); // find java tag
    render(article, tag_java);
}
```

and **view** below:

```html
#{extends 'main.html' /}

<h3>Article Title : ${article?.title}</h3>

Tags:<br>
<ol>
#{list article?.tags, as:'tag'}
    <li>${tag.tagName}</li>
#{/list}
</ol>

All article tagged <b>java</b> :
<ul>
#{list tag_java?.articles, as:'java_article'}
    <li>${java_article.title}</li>
#{/list}
</ul>
```

and lastly, the result is what to be expected :

[image: result]

---

**UPDATE**

This `@ManyToOne` relation is bi-directional. Providing with single data article, we can have all tag on that article, and also all of these tag can have all article data corresponding to each tag. The controller codes are similar, but without passing `Tag` object directly and the views look like following:

```html
#{extends 'main.html' /}

<h3>Article Title : ${article?.title}</h3>

Tags:<br>
<ol>
#{list article?.tags, as:'tag'}
    <li>${tag.tagName}</li>
#{/list}
</ol>

#{list article?.tags, as:'tag'}
Related article [tagged with ${tag.tagName}]:<br>
<ol>
    #{list tag?.articles, as:'article'}
        <li>${article.title}</li>
    #{/list}
</ol>
#{/list}
```

[image: bi-directional rel]

Comment: but, friend, it seems to it is useless. Why are you trying to get tag with findbyId. So it means there is no relation between your tables. I need somebody tell how to set ManyToMany relation on both side so that  I can query not all tags of this article but also all articles having this tag

Comment: Yeah friend, with using `@ManyToMany` you can make the relation bi-directional. Please see my updated answer above. Sorry for late response.