# What's the correct way to create a tagging system in Play Framework 2?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, many-to-many, relationship

I need to create this typical model: one `Question` can be tagged by multiple `Tags` and one `Tag` can be associated with multiple `Questions`. I think this calls for a `ManyToMany` relationship, and m[y question is very similar with this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286700/manytomany-relation-with-play-framework-1-2-5-jpa).

It's hard to find any examples of this situation for Play v2.x. I found [this example](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/guide6) on the documentation of Play 1.2.5 but it's severely outdated.

I would like to effeciently retrieve all `Questions` with a specific `Tag` and also retrieve all `Tags` of a specific `Question`. Can you tell me the structure of such classes and methods? I'm using the Java version of Play.

Comment: What db access api are you using, play scala or java?

Comment: updated question: I'm using Play Java

Comment: @biesior has answered similar questions for play 2.x [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419624/ebean-manytomany-query) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703629/filtermany-for-play-2-returns-all-results)